# why fql `SELECT recent_news FROM group WHERE gid = 2204685680` is empty?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want get the recent news from a group, I read the [fql/group](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group/)

and use `SELECT recent_news FROM group WHERE gid = 2204685680`, but the callback json data is empty.  Where am I wrong? Anyone can give me some suggestion? Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this field is not retrieving anything, I've tried it on my own "secret" testing group...but still no results.

So you *still* have two options:

1. Querying the `stream` table, something like
   `SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 2204685680`
2. Using the `feed` connection:
   `https://graph.facebook.com/2204685680/feed`

Comment: Thanks a lot, as your suggestion, I have get the data what I need.

Answer (score 0):

if the gid is the type of string then it will not return anything if u pass like this, try with 
SELECT recent_news FROM group WHERE gid = '2204685680'

Comment: still empty, test in this url:
`http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/`. and `2204685680` is a open group. it should be returned something...